# Creating WordPress Plugin solely for Admin panel with dash menu and submenus

Tags: plugins, menus, sub-menu

I am attempting to create a WordPress plugin which allows the client to use for help and other resources in a friendly interface. It would be desired if I could have guidance on creating a WordPress plugin with a main dashboard menu and submenus on it which can contain HTML content. As I am a new to WordPress Development, I found it hard to understand the WP Codex.

[image: snapshot]

This is the plugin code:

```
/** add menu. */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu', 'my_magic_function' );
add_submenu_page( 'my_plugin_menu', 'Page title', 'Sub-menu title', 'manage_options', 'my-submenu-handle', 'my_magic_function');


function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_options_page( 'Submenu', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-submenu-handle', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

/** html. */
function my_plugin_options() {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
                wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<p>Main page</p>';
        echo '</div>';
}

function my_plugin_options() {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
                wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<p>submenu page</p>';
        echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is pretty clear http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus, can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Wyck Here is my code, where am I wrong? http://pastebin.com/d4x4yD3L Thanks, Sam

Comment: Please post your code into your question and add any problems you are having with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the completecode on the comment section because it overrides the character limit. WordPress does not like this line of code when attempting to register a submenu: function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_options_page( 'Submenu', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-submenu-handle', 'my_plugin_options' );
} Here is the code on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LPFgxspQ

Comment: You should use `add_menu_page` or `add_options_page`, also you have several functions with the same name you cannot do that in PHP, turn on debugging http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress , also read the part about the callback `$function` on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I don't really get some of this - I'm quite bad at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you started with the right code. This creates a main menu item using `add_menu_page` then attaches a submenu using `add_submenu_page`. Both of them call a different function for the output.

Notice that the `add_submenu_page` function ties into the parent menu using `customteam` which is the `$menu_slug` of `add_menu_page`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'Team Kit', 'Team Kit', 'manage_options', 'customteam', 'my_custom_menu_page'); 
}

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'customteam', 'Team info', 'Team info', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page' ); 
    add_submenu_page( 'customteam', 'Crew Stats', 'Crew Stats', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page_2', 'my_custom_submenu_page_2' );
    //add_submenu_page_3 ... and so on
}

function my_custom_menu_page() {
    echo '<p>Hello, I am Team Kit</p>';
}

function my_custom_submenu_page() {
    echo '<p>Hello, I am Team Info</p>';
}

function my_custom_submenu_page_2() {
    echo '<p>Hello, I am Crew Stats</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how would I add additional subpage(s) to this plugin? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, and thanks for the amazing help!

Comment: Just call more `add_submenu_page`'s I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you, I have tried using the following code, but it does not display all the sub menus: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qj9k8XKm

Comment: You're missing add it to `add_action`, Ill fix my answer.

Comment: I have tried the new code and it says this as an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_submenu_page_2()

Comment: Woops I did that wrong the `add_action ` calls all the submenus in my example I thought for some reason I was using your example, mine is fixed. Your code example is wrong because you created a new function for each submenu call, you are making very basic PHP mistakes.

Comment: thanks again, but the same error shows up:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_submenu_page_2()

Comment: There was another typo, fixed.

Comment: I keep getting error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.". Tried so many ways, no one worked.